# Rails - validate uniqueness of input against other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, unique

I am trying to validate the uniqueness of a field against other fields on the same record.

For example, I have 10 inputs (let's say they are named field1, field2, field3, etc) and each field needs to be a number 1-10. I do not want the user to be able to the same number in an input twice.

Do I need to create a custom validation along the lines of show an error if field1 != field2 != field3 etc or is there a build in way to give a list of fields to all be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Activerecord does not have a defined validation to do this.

You have to create a custom validation on the lines

```
def model
  ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE = ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
  attributes_accessible :attr1, :attr2, :attr3
  validate :custom_validation

  def custom_validation
    unless self.attributes.select{|k,v| ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE.include?(k)}.values.uniq.length == ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE.length
      error.add("fields need to be uniq")
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Are you able to explain this a little bit? I don't understand this part - unless self.attributes.select{|k,v| ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE.include?(k)}.values.uniq.length == ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE.length
      error.add("fields need to be uniq")

Comment: ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE is the array of attributes you need to validate. The statement just selects key, value pairs of all the attributes you want to check uniqueness of. Then we take the values and then get only unique values and compare the length of the unique values to length of ATTRS_TO_VALIDATE. If the length is less then it means that there are similar values in the fields